# Docker image needed for building native C++ application for Windows

Tags: c++, windows, docker, cmake

I need a Docker image what later I can use in a CI/CD build plan.

This image is meant to define a container what runs a Windows environment and in which I can build a C++ application. For build I intend to use CMake and a command-line build tool generators.

So, I don't need Visual Studio or any other GUI application, just tools what I can call from command-line.

What I have already found, is an **official** MS learn page, [Install Build Tools into a container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/build-tools-container?view=vs-2022), presenting a Dockerfile. The problem with it is that out of box is alteady eronated, doesn't work. By building the image, it complains about the **curl** and the **start** command.

```
# escape=`

# Use the latest Windows Server Core 2022 image.
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022

# Restore the default Windows shell for correct batch processing.
SHELL ["cmd", "/S", "/C"]

RUN `
    # Download the Build Tools bootstrapper.
    curl -SL --output vs_buildtools.exe https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vs_buildtools.exe `
    `
    # Install Build Tools with the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.AzureBuildTools workload, excluding workloads and components with known issues.
    && (start /w vs_buildtools.exe --quiet --wait --norestart --nocache `
        --installPath "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools" `
        --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.AzureBuildTools `
        --remove Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.10240 `
        --remove Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.10586 `
        --remove Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.14393 `
        --remove Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows81SDK `
        || IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="3010" EXIT 0) `
    `
    # Cleanup
    && del /q vs_buildtools.exe

# Define the entry point for the docker container.
# This entry point starts the developer command prompt and launches the PowerShell shell.
ENTRYPOINT ["C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\Common7\\Tools\\VsDevCmd.bat", "&&", "powershell.exe", "-NoLogo", "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass"]
```

And the first attempt to build the image:

```
C:\temp> docker image build -t ci_win_x64:latest -m 4GB .
Sending build context to Docker daemon   2.15GB
Error response from daemon: dockerfile parse error on line 13: unknown instruction: curl
```

Surprise, the curl is missing. Should it be part of the official image?

Does anybody know a working Dockerfile for this kind of build? Based on your experince, what generator for CMake, would be the best?

Comment: If following the official instructions produces an error, odds are you are doing something wrong. Edit your question with a full transcript of you running the container image and any errors produced along the way.

Comment: Is the curl part of the official mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022 image?

Comment: How did you go from "parse error on line 13" to "curl is missing"? You should file an issue/feedback on the documentation if it does not work.

Comment: It might be the comment on the line before `curl` that's messing things up, since it doesn't have a continuation backtick at the end. Then Docker would interpret `curl` as a Dockerfile command. Try removing the comment line and see if it helps.

Comment: I have changed the "curl download" by adding the already downloaded vs_buildtools.exe file. And also removed the backticks and I left only the RUN command. But even so, no matter which BAT I am using, to set the CMD, I don't have a CL.exe

Comment: Edit your question to show your attempts to start the container image and invoke the compiler, and show concrete errors.